# Multithreading: best method for lossy thread notifications in Swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a high-priority audio thread that runs periodically and should do minimal synchronization.

Sometimes the main thread needs to ensure that at least one audio cycle has passed and certain parameters have been picked up, before sending the next batch of parameters. For example, when disabling an audio node the main thread needs to wait until the next cycle when the disabling command is picked up and the node shuts itself down.

At times it is important for the main thread to wait until the command is fully executed, but other times it's not important, so nobody might be listening to the sync event. Hence the "lossy" scenario.

So what is the best way of notifying other threads about an event with minimal overhead and possibly in a "lossy" way?

Can't think of ways of using a semaphore for this task. Are there any canonical ways of achieving this? Looks like Java's `notifyAll()` works precisely this way, if so, what synchronization mechanism is used behind `notifyAll()`?

Edit: been thinking, is there such a thing as "send me a semaphore in a queue and I'll signal it"? Seems a bit too complicated but theoretically it could do the job. Any simpler tools for the same task?

Comment: Here's an idea, perhaps half-baked: If the background operation is put onto a serial operation queue, the main operation can put itself onto that same operation queue, thus guaranteeing that it cannot start until that queue is cleared.

Comment: @matt sorry I didn't get which one of those is the audio thread in your terminology? Background or main? The goal is to have the audio thread notify other threads in the beginning of each cycle, if there are any currently waiting for the event. If there are none, the audio thread should proceed with absolute minimal overhead.

Comment: Waiting, semaphores, targeting the main queue, etc., are all technique that we’d advise against. I would suggest that we step back from questions like “what's the equivalent to `notifyAll`” or “how would I use semaphore” and instead perhaps you can give us real world example of a few requests that you want to make of your audio controller, 1 or 2 of the ones for which you want to “wait” and 1 or 2 of the ones that you don't mind being “lossy”. There are undoubtedly better patterns, but without real-world example of what you're trying to do, it’s hard to get specific.

Comment: It might also be useful to know what platform you're targeting and what audio frameworks you're using.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, you never want to block the main thread (or, at least, for more than a few milliseconds). If the response might ever take longer than that, rather than actually waiting, we would adopt asynchronous patterns, let the main thread proceed. Sure, if you need to prevent user interaction, we’d do that, but we wouldn't block the main thread.

The key concern is that if an app blocks the main thread for too long, you have a bad UX (where the app appears to freeze) and you risk having your app killed by the watchdog process. I would therefore not advise using semaphores (or any other similar mechanisms) to have the main thread `wait` for something from your audio engine controller.

So, for example, let’s say the main thread wants to tell the audio engine to pause playback, but you want the UI to “wait” for it to be acknowledged and handled. Instead of actually waiting, we would set up some asynchronous pattern where the main thread notifies the audio engine that it wants it to pause, the audio controller would then notify the main thread when that request has been processed via some callback mechanism (e.g., via delegate protocol pattern, completion handler closure, etc.). If you happen to need to prevent user interaction during the intervening time, then you’d disable controller and use some `UIActivityIndicatorView` (i.e., a spinner) or something like that, something that would be removed when the completion handler is called.

Now, you used the term “lossy”, but that generally conveys that you don't mind the request getting lost. But I’m assuming that is not really the case. I'm assuming that you don't really want the request to be lost, but rather only that the main thread doesn't care about the response, confident that the audio controller will get to it when it can. In that case, you'd probably still give this sort of request to the audio controller a callback mechanism, but the main thread just wouldn’t avail itself of it.

Now if you have a sequence of commands that you want the audio engine to process in order, then the audio controller might have a private, internal queue for these requests, where you’d configure it to not start subsequent request(s) until the prior ones finished. The main thread shouldn't be worried about whether the required audio cycle has processed. It should just send whatever requests are appropriate and the audio controller should handle them in the desired order/timing.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, you make some good points. The idea was inspired by the CoreAudio's own unit start/stop mechanism that is said to actually wait until the last audio cycle completes. But anyway, the alternative might be, e.g. I want to send a signal to disable an audio node and get a callback when it gets the signal and actually disables itself. Something like a non-blocking (Swift) `setEnabled(false, completion: { ... })`.  All such calls would be queued and executed in order. A delegate might work but would be limited to one listener.